# Create a set of vectors from given pairwise dot product

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra, code-review

Assume I am given a list of all the pairwise dot products of an unknown set of $n$ vectors. How can I efficiently generate such a set (or all possible sets) with the extra constraint that all vectors are unit vectors.

**What I have tried**

We can always choose the first vector to be the one that has 1 as its first component and 0 all the rest. Similarly, the second can have as the first element $p_{12}$ and the second $\sqrt{1-p_{12}^2}$, where $p_{ij}$ denotes the overlap between states $i,j$ and similarly for the rest.  That is,
$$
v_1=e_1 \notag \\
v_2=p_{12}e_1 + \sqrt{1-p_{12}^2} e_2 \notag \\
\vdots
$$
where $e_i$ denotes the $i-$th vector of an orthonormal basis.

My code for doing this is the following:

```
createStatesFromOverlaps[overlapMat_] := 
 Module[{st, sol, dim, cf, e},
  dim = Dimensions[overlapMat][[1]];
  e[x_] := UnitVector[dim, x];
  st = Table[
    Sum[e[i]*If[i == 1, overlapMat[[i, x]], cf[x, i]], {i, 1, x}], {x,
      1, dim}];
  sol = Solve[
    Table[
      st[[i]] . st[[j]] == overlapMat[[i, j]], {i, 1, dim}, {j, 1, 
       i}] // Flatten, 
    Table[cf[i, j], {i, 1, dim}, {j, 2, i}] // Flatten];
  Return[{st /. sol}]
  ]
```

The `overlapMat` is the given matrix $P$ of all possible overlaps, $p_{ij}$.

**The issue**

For two vectors this works well and it gives the correct result quickly usually. However, even for some simple 3 vector cases this takes ages to compute if the overlap matrix is exact and not numeric. If it is numeric, then it gives a warning about using Solve with inexact coefficients but otherwise gets a solution quickly. I was a bit surprised by that and was expecting the 3 vector case to be very quick, so I suspect that my implementation is not very clever.

**Question:**
My question is, can I modify the code in some clever way to solve this problem efficiently?

**Specific Example:**
Take as the matrix of overlaps the following one:

```
M={{1, ((1500 Sqrt[119] + 49 Sqrt[1365] + 7 Sqrt[23205] + 
     21 Sqrt[3885] (7 + Sqrt[17])) (3000 Sqrt[28886] + 
     Sqrt[30] (7 + Sqrt[17]) (111 + Sqrt[481])))/35000000000, (
  Sqrt[3] (7 + Sqrt[17]) (Sqrt[65] + 3 Sqrt[185]))/
  1000}, {((1500 Sqrt[119] + 49 Sqrt[1365] + 7 Sqrt[23205] + 
     21 Sqrt[3885] (7 + Sqrt[17])) (3000 Sqrt[28886] + 
     Sqrt[30] (7 + Sqrt[17]) (111 + Sqrt[481])))/35000000000, 1, (
  3 (500 Sqrt[21] + 21 Sqrt[455] + 63 Sqrt[1295] + 3 Sqrt[7735] + 
     9 Sqrt[22015]) (200 Sqrt[
      11110] + (7 + Sqrt[17]) (Sqrt[78] + 3 Sqrt[222])))/
  1400000000}, {(Sqrt[3] (7 + Sqrt[17]) (Sqrt[65] + 3 Sqrt[185]))/
  1000, (
  3 (500 Sqrt[21] + 21 Sqrt[455] + 63 Sqrt[1295] + 3 Sqrt[7735] + 
     9 Sqrt[22015]) (200 Sqrt[
      11110] + (7 + Sqrt[17]) (Sqrt[78] + 3 Sqrt[222])))/1400000000, 
  1}}
```

This seems to not compute in an expected time frame in my computer. However, it gives an immediate answer if I call the function as `createStatesFromOverlaps[M//N]` instead (but with the warning for inexact coefficients).

Thank you!

Comment: [Recovering a set of vectors from their Gram matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246615/recovering-a-set-of-vectors-from-their-gram-matrix)

Comment: Yep, I was suspecting I was missing something basic... Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is contained in $U\sqrt V$ where $UVW^\star=X$ is the singular value decomposition of your dot matrix $X$.

```
Remove["Global`*"]
dim = 6;
numvecs = 20;
originalVectors = RandomPoint[Sphere[dim], numvecs];
dotmtx = dotm[originalVectors];

dotm[vs_?(MatrixQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := Outer[Dot, vs, vs, 1]
loss[vs_?(MatrixQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := Total[Abs[dotmtx - dotm[vs]], 2]

{u, v, w} = SingularValueDecomposition[dotmtx];
isovecs = u . MatrixPower[v, 1/2][[All, ;; dim]];
```

`SingularValueDecomposition` also works on symbolic matrices too. If we use your example:

```
Remove["Global`*"]
dim = 3;
numvecs = 3;
originalVectors = RandomPoint[Sphere[dim], numvecs];
dotmtx = {{1, ((1500 Sqrt[119] + 49 Sqrt[1365] + 7 Sqrt[23205] + 
         21 Sqrt[3885] (7 + Sqrt[17])) (3000 Sqrt[28886] + 
         Sqrt[30] (7 + Sqrt[17]) (111 + Sqrt[481])))/
     35000000000, (Sqrt[3] (7 + Sqrt[17]) (Sqrt[65] + 3 Sqrt[185]))/
     1000}, {((1500 Sqrt[119] + 49 Sqrt[1365] + 7 Sqrt[23205] + 
         21 Sqrt[3885] (7 + Sqrt[17])) (3000 Sqrt[28886] + 
         Sqrt[30] (7 + Sqrt[17]) (111 + Sqrt[481])))/35000000000, 
    1, (3 (500 Sqrt[21] + 21 Sqrt[455] + 63 Sqrt[1295] + 
         3 Sqrt[7735] + 
         9 Sqrt[22015]) (200 Sqrt[
           11110] + (7 + Sqrt[17]) (Sqrt[78] + 3 Sqrt[222])))/
     1400000000}, {(Sqrt[3] (7 + Sqrt[17]) (Sqrt[65] + 3 Sqrt[185]))/
     1000, (3 (500 Sqrt[21] + 21 Sqrt[455] + 63 Sqrt[1295] + 
         3 Sqrt[7735] + 
         9 Sqrt[22015]) (200 Sqrt[
           11110] + (7 + Sqrt[17]) (Sqrt[78] + 3 Sqrt[222])))/
     1400000000, 1}};

dotm[vs_?(MatrixQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := Outer[Dot, vs, vs, 1]
loss[vs_?(MatrixQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := Total[Abs[dotmtx - dotm[vs]], 2]

{u, v, w} = SingularValueDecomposition[dotmtx];
isovecs = u . MatrixPower[v, 1/2][[All, ;; dim]];
Norm /@ N[isovecs]
loss[N@isovecs]
```

The result `isovecs` is very complicated but numerically comes out as this (up to isometry):

```
{{0.978501, 0.154241, -0.136916}, {0.637032, -0.770185, 0.0317041}, {0.921297, 0.368728, 0.123495}}
```

Comment: That is really nice! It can calculate the vectors exactly quickly (even if the answer is pretty horrible). That is what I was looking for. Thank you